# Python error when running clipper on heatmap

Tags: qgis-plugins, clip

I have created a heatmap from a delimited text layer and am trying to clip it to the boundaries of the map polygon. When I try to run the clipper I get this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>               File "C:/Users/Karongwe Base Manage/.qgis2/python/plugins\clipper\clipper.py", line 373, in run
>                 self.clip()
>               File "C:/Users/Karongwe Base Manage/.qgis2/python/plugins\clipper\clipper.py", line 122, in clip
>                 features = layer.getFeatures()          AttributeError: 'QgsRasterLayer' object has no attribute 'getFeatures'
>              2018-01-12T08:57:58    1   Traceback (most recent call last):
>               File "C:/Users/Karongwe Base Manage/.qgis2/python/plugins\clipper\clipper.py", line 373, in run
>                 self.clip()
>               File "C:/Users/Karongwe Base Manage/.qgis2/python/plugins\clipper\clipper.py", line 122, in clip
>                 features = layer.getFeatures()          AttributeError: 'QgsRasterLayer' object has no attribute 'getFeatures'

This is using a fresh install of QGIS 2.18.15. Can anyone help me? I am a novice with QGIS, I just know this process works on a different laptop here.

Comment: A fast try to avoid spaces in your file path might help.